# Why is FPS inside scrollable divs poorer compared to body scroll?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, scroll, google-chrome-devtools

I have a use case where I have to show a list of elements inside a scrollable `div`. The problem is that the list is long, close to 200 elements and when viewed in mobile browsers, the scroll is janky. I see a lot of `Paints` and `Composite Layers` in the chrome dev tools and effectively I am not able to achieve more than 30fps. Here is the sample code—

```
<style>
    body { 
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .scrollable {
        overflow: scroll;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<body>
<header></header>

<div class='scrollable'>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>    
</body>
```

After googling a bit I was able to get buttery smooth scrolls by putting a `overflow:scroll` on the `body` instead of the div. Though this works it doesn't seems intuitive to me that body scrolls are more performant than the ones applied on inner HTML elements.

Real Example: — https://funag.github.io
Actual Code: https://github.com/funag/ui-core/pull/80/commits/fe4a49fd92c3ad69a054308c4f2a89351178fb99

Comment: I'm interested by this subject too. But what's your question actually ?

Comment: I want to have as buttery smooth scrolls on inner elements as it is on body

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer?

Comment: I don't know exactly why this happens. I think it happens mostly because the the body scrolls are off loaded to the GPU directly where as the inner scrolls aren't.